# C# export grid to word using template

Tags: c#, ms-word, export, gridpanel

I have created a word template with some number and text fields and I export my data from my application like this:

```
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Object oTemplatePath = "C:\\MyTemplate.dotx";


        Application wordApp = new Application();
        Document wordDoc = new Document();

        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field myMergeField in wordDoc.Fields)
        {


            Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;

            String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;


            if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
            {

                Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");

                Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;

                String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);

                fieldName = fieldName.Trim();


                if (fieldName == "Name")
                {

                    myMergeField.Select();

                    wordApp.Selection.TypeText(txtSponsorResp.Text.ToString());

                }
                //other fields .....
            }
         }
         wordDoc.SaveAs("myFile.doc");
         wordApp.Documents.Open("myFile.doc");
         wordApp.Application.Quit();
```

And here is my code to export a grid to another word document:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.DataSource = bud; //where bud contains the datasource
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Export-Grid.doc");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

How can I use both of them and export all the fields and the grids in one document using a word template?

Comment: why word? why not excel?

Comment: I wonder if I may be easier to write the whole file in c# instead of trying to fill out a template.  you could make one class that is, in effect, the template, and it gets called by your function that has all the data fields

Comment: Are you doing the word template on the server?

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes

Comment: Kb257757 @aggicd. Instead use ClosedXML or Record a macro of word inserting the data, translate that to.net

Comment: @JeremyThompson ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over the field of the grid and insert them into the document using the aspose fields:

```
 Document wordDoc = new Document(myDoc);
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
      foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field myMergeField in wordDoc.Fields)
      {
          //iterate over fields and save to apose:
           doc.MyField = row.MyRow; 
      }
   }
//save To Aspose
```

**Aspose must know which of the fields you are going to populate**, if any. 
Else, it won't export anything.

furthermore, word doesn't act kindly with grids. It won't let you export a table because it cannot create one, unlike excel. 
instead of inserting an entire grid, just populate each and every field.